# Searching for engineering format numbers while stored in varchar format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, varchar

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

We have databases that I am supposed to support at work and all the actual values are being stored as `varchar`'s, long story behind it all.

Because of the reporting software we use our numbers need converted to decimal.
SQL Server doesn't seem to be able to convert scientific notation into decimal

EX: 6.54E-6

I tried doing a search for all values like '%e%' in hopes of finding them all then I could manually convert them all to normal number formats... however that did not work.

Is there a way I can mass convert? Or at the very least search for all values that are containing the E??

I have tried searching for E and I cannot look for values < a given number.. because they are stored as `varchar`.

Any ideas would be much appreciated, I probably won't look at this for a few hours (I won't be at work again for 12 hours so if I don't respond right away that is why). Thanks so much in advanced any solution will save me hours of searching.

Comment: What query did you try for the 'mass convert'?

Comment: @TT   I don't know of any to use for a mass convert, How I figured out this was the problem was trying to run queries over a date range and slowly narrowing down the date range to find 1 specific entry and machine.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to cast the value to a float:

```
select (case when isnumeric(val) = 1 then cast(val as float) end)
from t;
```

Ironically, one of the weaknesses of `isnumeric()` in most circumstances is that it recognizes scientific notation.  Here, that is an advantage.

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `try_convert()`:

```
select try_convert(float, val)
from t;
```

Comment: My only problem with your post is I am using SQL Server 2008. I just tried a query, and it seemed to work. What our reports were doing was 'cast(Value as Decimal(18,2))' if I change that to 'cast(Value as float)' it did finish the query. I will have to wait until tonight to try this on the actual production equipment.